# Does Invertase catalyse the hydrolysis of other sugars other than sucrose?

Tags: molecular-biology, proteins, enzymes, enzyme-kinetics, sugar

I recently did a lab where we tested out the substrate specificity of Invertase on different types of sugars such as sugar alcohols and disaccharides, measured by the absorbance of red using a colorimeter. Our results indicated that lactose and maltose were more effectively hydrolysed than the sugar alcohols sorbitol, inositol and mannitol. I'm guessing this could be because lactose and maltose are similar in structure to sucrose, which it normally hydrolyses, however, I was hoping there was a more concrete answer.

Comment: Welcome to the site. What research have you done on your own to answer this question? The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way.

Comment: Please finish reading the [Tour] before posting here.  And check the Help on Asking Good Questions.